# Displaying Line Chart on Bar Chart exactly like web via python openpyxl

Tags: python, charts, openpyxl

I'm trying to imitate the chart for `Annual Financial Highlight` in [here](https://www.malaysiastock.biz/Corporate-Infomation.aspx?securityCode=0159).

[image: generate_by_web]

Basically, this is their data, which I scrape and conditioned them :

```
    if netProfit == 0 or revenue == 0 :
        print("Cannot Divide")
        profitMargin = "///"
    else :
        profitMargin = round((float((netProfit/revenue)*100)),1)
        print("Profit Margin (%) = " + str(profitMargin))
```

Note that `///` is replacing `float division by zero` error:

[image: web_scrape_data]

From my coding below, this is what I can generate currently, which is the `Profit Margin (%)` is not appearing as per web showing :

[image: generate_by_me]

My code :

```
        chart1 = BarChart()
        chart1.title = "Annual Financial Highlight"
        chart1Data = Reference(lws, min_col=36, min_row=74, max_row=84, max_col=37)
        chart1.add_data(chart1Data, titles_from_data=True)
        s1 = chart1.series[0]
        s2 = chart1.series[1]
        s1.dLbls = DataLabelList()
        s2.dLbls = DataLabelList() 
        s1.dLbls.showVal = True
        s2.dLbls.showVal = True
        s1.dLbls.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
        s2.dLbls.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
        
        chart2 = LineChart()
        chart2Data = Reference(lws, min_col=35, min_row=74, max_row=84, max_col=35)
        chart2.add_data(chart2Data, titles_from_data=True)
        s3 = chart2.series[0]
        s3.dLbls = DataLabelList()
        s3.dLbls.showVal = True
        s3.smooth = True
        s3.dLbls.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
        
        
        chart1.y_axis.crosses = "max"
        chart1 += chart2
        
        quarterChart = Reference(lws, min_col=34, min_row=75, max_row=84)
        chart1.set_categories(quarterChart)
        
        chart1.shape = 4
        chart1.height = 10
        chart1.width = 20
        
        chart1.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
        chart1.y_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
        
        chart1.x_axis.scaling.orientation = "maxMin"
        chart1.y_axis.scaling.orientation = "minMax"
        
        lws.add_chart(chart1, "X52")
```

How can I make the `Line Chart` to appear exactly as per web?

Thanks!

Comment: Profit Margin (%) Revenue (RM mil) Profit After Tax (RM mil)
31 Mar 2022 25.3   0.6   0.2
31 Mar 2021 ///   0   -1.3
30 Sep 2020 -119.3   0.4   -0.5
31 Dec 2019 -111.9   1.2   -1.3
30 Sep 2019 ///   0   -1.6
31 Dec 2018 -23.5   13.4   -3.1
31 Dec 2017 14.9   15.4   2.3
31 Dec 2016 -104.7   9.6   -10
31 Dec 2015 -948.8   11.1   -105.6
31 Dec 2014 -97.4   20.9   -20.4

Comment: Both charts are using the same y-axis but you need different ones for the scaling effect.

Comment: How to set the scaling? @CharlieClark